# Using "git submodule add" in native Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to use the *git submodule add* command in Visual Studio 2019 without installing any add-ons? I use the GitHub tools provided by VS2019 and I would like to use just that and the built-in command line, but it seems that only some specific Git commands are supported...

[image: VS02019 Command Window]